# Getting inaccurate remainders with modulus operator (%)

Tags: java, netbeans, precision, floating-action-button, modulo

I'm new to Java and learning about the % operator. However I have a problem:

System.out.println(510%5); //this produces a correct output of 0

System.out.println((5.1*100)%(0.05*100)); //but this produces 4.9999

Technically they're the same numbers, but why are the outputs different?

Comment: A question that [gets asked a lot](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java&oq=s&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+floating+point+precision) on this and on many other sites.

Comment: It is a remainder operator, not a modulus operator.

Comment: Try `System.out.println(5.1*100)` and `System.out.println(0.05*100)`.  The second one happens to round to the correct value, but the first one does not.